# Accessing different networks with different subnets from one main network

Tags: router, subnet

I have multiple branches with their own NBN connections and routers, i would like to put each one on a different subnet (192.168.2.*, 192.168.3.* and so on) just for sorting reasons, they do not need to communicate with each other at all.

But i have a portable network (portable as in location wise) so just a router and computers connected to it, which i bring on site to each branch, i would like this one to be able to communicate with all the branches and access all devices on each network.

So the portable network router can be 192.168.1.* which has other devices on that network, when i bring it onto a branch am i able to run a network cable from one of the branches routers into the portable router which will give the portable router Internet from the branch and also allow the portable network computers to communicate with the branch networks?

Sorry if i have explained this really crazy, i have set the branch routers subnet mask to 255.255.0.0 same as the portable routers, the portable router WAN is configured with DHCP so it can access the different branch networks, this does give the portable network internet but i am unable to ping another device from one network to the other, the machine also have a subnet of 255.255.0.0.

Can anyone point me in the right direction or is this not really possible with normal home network routers such as a Telstra modem, would i require a specific router?

Answer (score 1):

We could simplify your situation. You just need VPN access to all your branches. In this case you need hardware and software that support VPN connection in all your brances.